# How can I render my popup component over a Container or Div instead of below to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angularjs

Currently my popup component 'Category' is showing below to my Container Div.

My rendering component to the ui

```
 return (
    <div style={{ margin: 80, marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30 }}>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={6} md={8}>
            <h3 className="headLine">Curated Food Categories</h3>
          </Col>
          <Col lg={2} md={1}></Col>
          <Col lg={4} md={3}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
              <Button onClick={() => setCategoryBtn(true)} className="categoryBtn">Add Category </Button>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <hr style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} />
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <TableContainer
              style={{ boxShadow: "none", borderRadius: "10px" }}
              component={Paper}
            >
         ...
            </TableContainer>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

Category component which I'm trying to popup over the container

```
    <Category trigger={categoryBtn} setTrigger={setCategoryBtn}>
     <h3>Pop up screen</h3>
    </Category>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render **Container** component using ternary condition and based on your click(Selection) alternate component will render.

render **Category** component like below

```
   <>
    { !categoryBtn ? 
     <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col lg={6} md={8}>
                <h3 className="headLine">Curated Food Categories</h3>
              </Col>
              <Col lg={2} md={1}></Col>
              <Col lg={4} md={3}>
                <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
                  <Button onClick={() => setCategoryBtn(true)} className="categoryBtn">Add Category </Button>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <hr style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} />
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <TableContainer
                  style={{ boxShadow: "none", borderRadius: "10px" }}
                  component={Paper}
                >
             ...
                </TableContainer>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        :
       <Category trigger={categoryBtn} setTrigger={setCategoryBtn}>
         <h3>Pop up screen</h3>
        </Category>
    }
  </>
```

Are you looking something like this

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Modal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Open</button>
      </div>
      {open && (
        <div className="modal">
          <div>Modal Opened</div>
          <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Close</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Working [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/open-modal-e4c4m)

> You can render component using ternary condition.

Comment: Thanks but I want to overshadow the category component instead of replacing the Container

Comment: @mani are you looking modal like i have updated at bottom.